# galvanized or stainless turnbuckles for exterior wire rope fence?

Tags: fence, steel, corrosion, stainless, galvanic-corrosion

I'm working on a wire rope fence that looks [like this](http://www.newcore.net.in/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/Invisible-Protection-Fence-Stainless-Steel-Wire-Rope2.jpg). The difference is that we live fairly close to the ocean, which means lots of salty air.

I've bought 1/8" galvanized steel with plastic coating and stainless screw eyes attached to the posts. What's missing are the turnbuckles.

Ideally, I would like to buy stainless turnbuckles. The issue is that they don't sell them locally, and amazon is the only store that ships to my country and has a good selection of rather inexpensive stainless turnbuckles, [like these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B015ASQP78).

On the other hand, I can find good [galvanized steel turnbuckles like these](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07F6WQC7C) anywhere. Those are the two options.

It seems that the galvanized steel turnbuckles are stronger. The problem is that I don't know how long they'll last being so close to the ocean. I can buy the stainless steel turnbuckles, but most of the ones sold in amazon say "light duty" and are being sold by questionable sellers.

Would it be a mistake to buy galvanized steel? Just to give you an idea of how bad the corrosion here is: I bought [these pliers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00079LN1Y), and they had shallow rust spots one week later.

Answer (score 2):

The age-old question of whether or not to use alloy materials is subjective.

- cost vs. longevity
- consequence/cost of failure

Rest assured that the galvanized components *will* fail. You will then be unable to adjust the tension of the cables. If the consequences of the failure outweigh the initial investment for alloy materials, you should buy stainless (this includes the cable itself as well).

For decades and decades the oil industry resisted the use of alloys in piping and vessel construction due to cost; it was just easier and cheaper to replace carbon steel components at their earlier end-of-life. Now, the safety and environmental costs of failure are beginning to outweigh the cost of investment for alloy materials, hence they are now "alloying up".

Answer (score 2):

Galvanized will last forever in a desert and a few years " close to the ocean". Stainless usually means 304 or 316 ; 316 is better near the ocean . Very pricey but, monel would be the best ; available as boat hardware at a marine supply source.

Answer (score 0):

I have used galvanized messenger wire for services throughout my career to support feeder wires and service entrance wires and have never heard of a failure (other than wind damage from storms on the west coast of USA.) In fact many steel items can be recoated with a zinc rich paint or cold process galvinization spray paint. One thing that have seen if plastic coated wire is used after a few years the plastic coating may discolor and crack, even the covering that has UV protection lasted less than 10 years however the wire rope is still in good shape after 20+ years. I did repaint several of the wire clamps about 6 or 7 years ago as they were showing rust spots but I do expect this to outlast me.

Answer (score 0):

"swageless stainless steel turnbuckle tensioners with lag screws" - quote from a deleted answer, and what you should be looking for imo, just like the suggestion in [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/148542/23295) on your other question.

Or even better, 'swage*able* stainless steel turnbuckle tensioners *without* lagscrews' (the hidden kind, like what I'd assume they used in the picture, and what you're SO probably expects it to look like).

---

Obviously SS will last longer, that choice is up to you, but if you want it to look like a picture out of *Better Homes and Gardens*, it *will* be stainless, and use hidden fasteners. Neither anything galvanized nor classic style turnbuckles will be involved.

You've been advised to search marine stores for hardware, but anything with boats arbitrarily triples the cost. Luckily you're after railing hardware, which is only double....